# How to make electron application menu accessible on windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, desktop-application, electron

I currently have an app built using [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) that has the following application menu:

```
'My app', 'Edit', 'View', 'Window', 'help'
```

If you have voice over on, these items are accessible on a mac out of the box via the shortcut '**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>**'. However, in windows, they are not accessible out of the box. It is impossible for me to get to it by just using the keyboard.

The windows shortcut to access the application's menu is '**<kbd>Alt</kbd>**'. When you hit tab, most applications will give you a hint of what letter you have to press next to get to that menu item. For instance, to get to the 'File' menu itme you can do '**<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>**', for View you can do '**<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>**' and so forth. 
How do I go about implementing this behavior for an electron app?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows such access keys are commonly referred to as mnemonics, you can add one to a menu item by inserting a `&` into the menu item label right in front of the character you want to use as the access key. For example if you create a top-level menu with a label of `&About` you'll be able to access it by pressing `Alt + A`.

Comment: Should the & symbol appear before the text even for BIDI languages?